# how to put compiler command line args in specific places using cmake

Tags: g++, cmake, gnu, ld

So I'm building a shared library, out of two static libraries.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649792/602340) says the way to do it is to insert `-Wl,--whole-archive` before my static libs, the `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` after them.

So what I have in cmake at the moment for the shared library is:

```
add_library(wittyPlus SHARED empty.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wittyPlus 
    ${wtdbosqlite}
    ${WT_LIBRARIES}
    ${DB_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    app models
)
```

So what I need is for it to add the `-Wl,--whole-archive` before `app` and `models`, then `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` after them (so that the standard library imports don't get exported by the shared lib).

What's the easiest way to do this in CMake ?

---

**Addition:** So I'd like to use the standard cmake stuff as much as possible, that way I don't have to do any extra work for windows builds, as CMake kindly removes the compiler definitions that aren't supported on the platform being built.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK, it was much easier than I thought.

So according to the [cmake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:target_link_libraries):

> Item names starting with '-', but not '-l' or '-framework', are
>   treated as linker flags.

So the fix was just to:

```
add_library(wittyPlus SHARED empty.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wittyPlus 
    ${wtdbosqlite}
    ${WT_LIBRARIES}
    ${DB_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    "-Wl,--whole-archive"
    app models
    "-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
)
```

I don't know if it'll work on windows or not, I expect it will as cmake is super clever.

Looking at the result with objdump, it does seem to have a lot of boost stuff in the exports, so I might be doing something wrong.

```
objdump -C -t wittyPlus/libwittyPlus.so | grep -i boost
```

But it does have the stuff I need to link against it so, that's a step forward.

Any other answers still appreciated. Basically what I'm trying to do is the same as this question:

[CMake: how create a single shared library from all static libraries of subprojects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429055/cmake-how-create-a-single-shared-library-from-all-static-libraries-of-subprojec)

Comment: Have you found a work around that doesn't require a null `empty.cpp` file?

Comment: No, I use empty.cpp all the time.

Comment: I looks like you can do `file(WRITE empty.cpp "")` if you don't want to pollute your real source tree with junk files.

Comment: In case your compiler doesn't like to compile empty cpp files (error message), sacrifice a few bytes in your binary and replace the "" with something like "int dummy = 0;".

Comment: on windows it's /WHOLEARCHIVE

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Saved a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

If you are building the static libraries yourself, you can use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29824424/4069571 namely building them as object libraries first, then linking them into the respective shared and static libs.