# CMake: Visual Studio Project Created Using OBJECT Library Feature

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmake

I'm using CMAKE to create have the following Visual Studio Solution layout:

```
Solution  
    + Project1 (C)  
    + Project2 (Fortran)
```

The goal is to create a C wrapper (Project1) around the Fortran routines (Project2) combined into a single shared library. To do so, I need to link the .obj file produced in the Fortran project with that produced in the C project. This is possible using the OBJECT library feature (introduced in CMake 2.8.8). [Detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429055/cmake-how-create-a-single-shared-library-from-all-static-libraries-of-subprojec)

`Project1` creates the shared library and `Project2` creates the .obj file.

In the CMakeLists.txt of Project1 I use:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib1${lib1_src} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib2>)
```

In the CMakeLists.txt of Project2 I use:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib2 OBJECT ${lib2_src})
```

In the CMakeLists.txt of Solution I use:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)

PROJECT (Test)

ENABLE_LANGUAGE (C)
ENABLE_LANGUAGE (Fortran)

SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(project1)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(project2)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(project1) 
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(project2)`
```

The issue I'm having has do do with the C Project produced by CMake. Specifically, the **Runtime Library** setting under Properties --> Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Code Generation is defaulted to **Multi-threaded DLL** regardless of what the Solution configuration is current set to (Debug | Release).

[image: Improper Configuration]

The issue seems to be related to the use of `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>` expression since removing that will result in creation of a C Project that properly configures the Runtime Library based on the Solution configuration.

[image: Proper Configuration]

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can modify the CMAKE files to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by adding a 3rd project which aggregates the .obj files into a shared library.

```
Solution  
    + Project1 (C)  
    + Project2 (Fortran)
    + Project3 (SharedLib)
```

In the CMakeLists.txt of Project1 I use:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib1 OBJECT ${lib1_src})
```

In the CMakeLists.txt of Project2 I use:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib2 OBJECT ${lib2_src})
```

In the CMakeLists.txt of Project3 I use:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(libName SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Project1> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Project2>)
```