# Cmake: linking to static internal library without exporting it

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I have a project with this structure:

```
/path/to/my/project
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── internal-libs
│   ├── internal-lib1
├── libs
│   ├── lib1
│   ├── lib2
```

`lib1` is a static library.

`lib2` is a static library.

`internal-lib1` is a static library.

lib2 links statically to lib2 and internal-lib1. `lib1` and `lib2` are going to be exported but `internal-lib1` will be left behind. For the linkage, I have:

```
target_link_libraries(lib2 PRIVATE internal-lib1)
target_link_libraries(lib2 PRIVATE lib1)
```

My understanding is that because I am linking statically and privately, All the information about internal-lib1 would be contained in lib2 and that I won't have to export internal-lib1 to the outside world.

However, when I try to use it in a client program, I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld cannot find -llib-internal1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

in my generated Export config file, I have:

```
# Create imported target lib2
add_library(lib2 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib2 PROPERTIES
INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "$<LINK_ONLY:lib1>;**$<LINK_ONLY:internal-lib1>**"
)
# Create imported target lib1
add_library(lib1 STATIC IMPORTED)
```

Am I misunderstanding the static linking or is there something wrong with my setup? I am using cmake 3.2.2. All my target includes are PRIVATE. I don't understand why `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` is populated with entries and what LINK_ONLY means.

p.s. Actually lib1 and lib2 are supposed to be shared libraries but I can't even get the static version working so for simplicity here I am describing the static case for the exportable libraries.

Answer (score 4):

For static libaries `lib1` and `lib2`, the CMake command

```
target_link_libraries(lib2 PRIVATE lib1)
```

does not imply that the library `lib1` is copied to the library `lib2` upon linking. The `PRIVATE` keyword only affects [transitive usage requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements) of the library `lib1` when another library links to `lib2`.

To have CMake merge `lib1` into `lib2` upon linking, use `libtool` and a `POST_BUILD` action:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET lib2 POST_BUILD
    COMMAND /usr/bin/libtool -static -o $<TARGET_FILE:lib2>
    $<TARGET_FILE:lib2> $<TARGET_FILE:lib1>
```

In that case, there is no need to link `lib1` to `lib2` with `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: I see thanks. I was basically trying to do what is attempted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11448878/4376555) for the simple case of static libraries as I thought that his methods but unnecessarily complicated. However I think your solution is even more hacky.

Comment: "does not imply that the library lib1 is copied to the library lib2 upon linking."

That's not true for shared libraries: lib1's .a definitely gets copied inside lib2's .so

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create object library instead of static library:

```
add_library(foo OBJECT foo.cpp)
add_executable(baz $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo> baz.cpp)
```

You can find more docs about this feature here: https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rejected/object-libraries.html