# Merging multiple dynamic libraries into one using Cmake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I got a project that uses Cmake and has a configuration to create a shared library. This project has some external dependencies (like zlib, etc). Generating  shared library and linking against it would require not only providing dll generated by the project, but also dlls for all dependancies (since the library itself is linked against other libraries).

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a single dll of that project, that would have statically linked all dependencies into it. I tried creating an `OBJECT` library and using it to create a `SHARED` library with Cmake, but had no luck with this approach. Is this can be achieved?

Unfortunately static linking of the whole library is not an option due to licensing issues and I'd like to avoid attaching 10 dlls to the application package. I need that only for Windows.

Comment: You can not reasonably merge DLLs with any tool since they are not really code at that point and cross-dependencies would be a bitch if you tried to do it at byte-level. Without access to the code or static libraries for all the dependencies, you're completely out of luck. CMake and Visual Studio have nothing to do with it.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with cmake, because cmake doesn't really do anything with the libraries. Your other tools do. Please edit the question to make it unrelated to cmake.

Comment: @utopia Of course you can do exactly what the dynamic linker does, but simply ahead of time. I'm not aware of any tools that do that, though, so it'd be a case of roll-your-own.

Comment: @utopia thanks. I got access to the source code and to static libraries for all dependencies. I just wanted to merge all of these libraries into single dll (`add_library(project_name SHARED ...`)

Comment: @KubaOber the project is built with cmake and there is similar technique described: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429055/cmake-how-create-a-single-shared-library-from-all-static-libraries-of-subprojec
The only problem with it is that it uses `--export-all-symbols` which has no simple alternative on MSVC (`/WHOLEARCHIVE` does not work)

Comment: The answer you link to has nothing to do with dynamic libraries! And again - that you use cmake is irrelevant. As soon as you find a tool, any tool, that can pre-link DLLs together, you can then use it with any build system. Adding custom tools to cmake is fairly easy.